# get input type value from html to android

Tags: java, android, html, input, webview

I want to make a web view calculator. Let's I have an HTML base calculator UI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="calc">
    <input type="text" name="screen" disabled> <br>
    <hr>
    <input type="button" value="&radic;" onclick="calc.screen.value = Math.sqrt(calc.screen.value);">
    <input type="button" value="CE" onclick="calc.screen.value = ''">
    <input type="button" value="C" onclick="calc.screen.value = ''">
    <input type="button" value="&larr;" onclick="calc.screen.value = calc.screen.value.slice(0,-1);"> <br>

    <input type="button" value="7">
    <input type="button" value="8">
    <input type="button" value="9">
    <input type="button" value="+">

    <br>

    <input type="button" value="4">
    <input type="button" value="5">
    <input type="button" value="6">
    <input type="button" value="-">

    <br>

    <input type="button" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="2">
    <input type="button" value="3">
    <input type="button" value="*">

    <br>

    <input type="button" value="0">
    <input type="button" value=".">
    <input type="button" value="=">
    <input type="button" value="/"> <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to get value from a button and then I will calculate in an android java class. After this, the final result will show in HTML.

**How can I get input typed value from HTML to android and pass back?**

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Android JavaScriptInterface class to get data from html input field.

JavaScriptInterface have processFormData() method return data as a string.

then you can process this data what you want .

you found some [example here](https://gist.github.com/adrobisch/734117)